# Python Overwriting List Element

Tags: python, list, append

Is there a quick and easy way that is not computationally expensive to overwrite an element in a list corresponding to an element in another list (of the same length)?

```
iterates = input("How many iterates: ")
trials = input("How many trials: ")

aggregateList = [iterates]

def function():
    recordList = []

    for i in range(iterates):
        # math goes here
        recordList.append()

    aggregateList[i] += recordList[i]

for i in range(trials):
    function()
```

The problem is coming from `aggregateList[i] += recordList[i]`Any ideas on something else that will work? Say the value in recordList[i] is 5 for the first "iteration", 5 for the second, 5 for the third, at this time aggregateList[i] should be 15.

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing and it is hard to understand what your application is. Could you not use a dictionary instead? What are you appending to recordList? What exactly is going in your aggregateList? What is your purpose of aggregateList = [iterates]?

Comment: I'm doing scientific computing.. the first element of recordList is an initial condition, usually zero or 1, from there a formula is applied to it and its value is sent to recordList[i+1] (if the function was applied to recordList[i]). I hope for aggregateList to be the sum of each trial of recordList

Comment: Even though it won't name itself this way, the first loop of function in `for i in range(iterates)` will produce list1, i=2 will produce list 2, etc... I hope for aggregateList in the `i`th spot to hold the value list1[i]+list2[i]+list3[i]+...list_range[i]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for either:

```
aggregateList += recordList
```

or

```
aggregateList.append(recordList)
```

depending on whether you want your aggregate to be flat or nested.

And change `aggregateList = [iterates]` to `aggregateList = []`.

This is how I personally would implement it:

```
iterates = input("How many iterates: ")
trials = input("How many trials: ")

def function():
    recordList = []

    for i in range(iterates):
        # math goes here
        recordList.append()

    return recordList

aggregateList = []
for i in range(trials):
    aggregateList.append(function())
```

Or even:

```
def calculate (i): pass #math goes here
#nested:
aggregateList = [[calculate(i) for i in range(iterates)] for _ in range(trials)]
#flat:
aggregateList = [x for trial in ([calculate(i) for i in range(iterates)] for _ in range(trials)) for x in trial]
```

Comment: Now I'm getting UnboundLocalError, whereas before I was getting indexed error

Comment: True, in order to assign to a global variable, you have to declare it as such. Insert `global aggregateList` as first line of `function`.

Comment: @Questioneer Please see the edit to my answer. I included a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume you've have a list of lists (in a variable name lists). This would be after you have called your 'function()' function (not the greatest function name by the way) and collected your recordLists in a list.

```
trials = 3
lists = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

for i in range(trials):
    aggregateList = [reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [listn[i] for listn in lists]) for i in range(trials)]

print aggregateList
```

would output

```
[12, 15, 18]
```

which I think is the type of solution you are looking for.

reduce is a fun function from functional programming. It allows you to apply the anonymous function lambda continuously to items of a list and then return the accumulated value. So in this case, it is preforming (1+4)+7,(2+5)+8,(3+6)+9. The list we are applying reduce to is constructed through a comprehension to extract the i's from the lists inside lists. The call to reduce is wrapped inside another comprehension to return a list of the results.

Comment: This answer is in response to the OP's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

So `iterates` is a number like 4, and `trials` another like 3.

```
aggregateList = [iterates]
```

now `aggregateList = [4]`.  What's the purpose of that?

```
def function():
    recordList = []

    for i in range(iterates):
        # math goes here
        recordList.append()
```

what are you appending to `recordList`?  That last line should produce an error like: `append() takes exactly one argument (0 given)`

```
    aggregateList[i] += recordList[i]
```

what is `i` at this point?  The last value of the above iteration, i.e. `iterates-1 =3`, or is supposed to be the `trials` iterator.  How many items do you expect `aggregateList` to have at this point?  As written I expect it to give an error: `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`.

```
for i in range(trials):
    function()
```

What is 'the problem'?  What error message or bad result were you getting?

I suspect you are more familiar with another language, and trying to apply its idioms to Python.  Also, get the calculation working before worrying about efficiency.  At some point, though you might want to use `numpy` which adds arrays, and the ability to do math on a whole array at once.